# Cordova Facebook login integration undefined cordovaOauth

Tags: cordova, oauth, facebook-login, ngcordova

I'm trying to integrate Facebook Login into a cordova app not using ionic, following this example:
[How to Integrate Facebook Login into a Cordova Based App](https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-integrate-facebook-login-into-a-cordova-based-app/)

When pressing the login button I have this error on the logcat:

`cannot read property facebook of undefined' at the line $cordovaOauth.facebook`

Comment: Have you activated the InAppBrowser plugin? Check if you meet the requirements for that plugin in https://github.com/nraboy/ng-cordova-oauth (Requirements)

Comment: These requirements are set, i d'ont know what coudn't work.
I used **phonegap-facebook-plugin** [https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin] it's more simple

Answer (score 0):

For social integration you can use simply 
$cordovaFacebook it is very easy plugin where you can integrate with Facebook..
Checkout this link for any instructions 
[$cordovaFacebook Plugin](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/facebook/)